# Parsing XML in python - stumped how to do this

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I've looked through a number of support pages, examples and documents however I am still stumped as to how I can achieve what I am after using python.

I need to process/parse an xml feed and just take very specific values from the XML document. Which is where I am stumped.

The xml looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed>
 <title type="text">DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData</title>
 <id></id>
 <updated>2014-12-03T07:44:30Z</updated>
 <link rel="self" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData" />
 <entry>
 <id></id>
<title type="text"></title>
<updated>2014-12-03T07:44:30Z</updated>
<author>
  <name />
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(6235)" />
<category />
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">6235</d:Id>
    <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2014-12-01T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
    <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.01</d:BC_1MONTH>
    <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.03</d:BC_3MONTH>
    <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.08</d:BC_6MONTH>
    <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.13</d:BC_1YEAR>
    <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.49</d:BC_2YEAR>
    <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.9</d:BC_3YEAR>
    <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.52</d:BC_5YEAR>
    <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.93</d:BC_7YEAR>
    <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.22</d:BC_10YEAR>
    <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.66</d:BC_20YEAR>
    <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.95</d:BC_30YEAR>
    <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.95</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
  </m:properties>
 </content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id></id>
<title type="text"></title>
<updated>2014-12-03T07:44:30Z</updated>
<author>
  <name />
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(6236)" />
<category />
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">6236</d:Id>
    <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2014-12-02T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
    <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.04</d:BC_1MONTH>
    <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.03</d:BC_3MONTH>
    <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.08</d:BC_6MONTH>
    <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.14</d:BC_1YEAR>
    <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.55</d:BC_2YEAR>
    <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.96</d:BC_3YEAR>
    <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.59</d:BC_5YEAR>
    <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2</d:BC_7YEAR>
    <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.28</d:BC_10YEAR>
    <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.72</d:BC_20YEAR>
    <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">3</d:BC_30YEAR>
    <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">3</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
  </m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
</feed>
```

This XML document gets a new Entry appended each day for the duration of the month when it resets and starts again on the 1st of the next month.

I need to extract the date from d:NEW_DATE and the value from d:BC_10YEAR, now when there is just a single entry this is no problem, however I am struggling to work out how to have it go through the file and extracting the relevant date and value from each ENTRY block.

Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: I had to remove a bunch or URL links in the XML so that I could post it up. I don't believe them missing should have any impact on the solution though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is probably the easiest way to do what you're looking for:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

xmldoc = open('datafile.xml', 'r').read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(xmldoc)

entryList = bs.findAll('entry')

for entry in entryList:
    print entry.content.find('m:properties').find('d:new_date').contents[0]
    print entry.content.find('m:properties').find('d:bc_10year').contents[0]
```

You can then replace the `print` with whatever you want to do with the data (add to a list etc.).

Comment: Thanks for this, I have been playing around a bit with BeautifulSoup so will definitely give this a go and let you know if it has worked.

Comment: With a little tweaking of the above I have managed to get this working the way I needed. Many thanks!

Comment: Not to worry, glad I could help :). Feel free to give the answer a +1 upvote for usefulness ;)

Comment: As soon as I have a high enough reputation rating to up tick the answer I will!